# Symfony2, Doctrine, Empty entity in relationships

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have two entities one is main and second is additional, they joined as OneToOne. I won't show all, i think it's not necessary:

**apiKey**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Eve\ApiBundle\Entity\Account\apiKeyInfo", inversedBy="apiKey_byKeyID")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="keyID", referencedColumnName="keyID")
 */
private $apiKeyInfo_byKeyID;

public function get_apiKeyInfo_byKeyID()
{
    return $this->apiKeyInfo_byKeyID;
}
```

**apiKeyInfo**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Eve\ProfileBundle\Entity\apiKey", mappedBy="apiKeyInfo_byKeyID")
 */
private $apiKey_byKeyID;

public function get_apiKey_byKeyID()
{
    return $this->apiKey_byKeyID;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $type;


/**
 * @param string $type
 * @return apiKeyInfo
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string 
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}
```

Relation i call in twig (apiKey is goten in php part)

```
apiKey.get_apiKeyInfo_byKeyID.type
```

It works fine when db tables is full of data, but when "apiKeyInfo" table doesn't have same keyID it throw me exception:

```
Entity was not found.
```

I understand why, because it cannot find entries with same keyID ... But i don't know how to deal with it.

So question is...
How can i make result, of this relation, can be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was in incorrect descriptions of entity. Problem solved.